# JSONparse won't do with Asyncstorage retrieved item

Tags: react-native

I'm coding a simple app, and I want to store the user info on the device, and include them in a POST request without keep asking the user for them. So I thought: "let's save them on the device!".

I've managed to store them, but when I retrieve them, I just can't figure how to JSONparse it back to a dict.

Here's what I get when I call the AsyncStorage.getItem:

I/ReactNativeJS(31854): ## STORAGE - Data retrieved: [object Object]

And when I try to pass that through JSONparse, I get "JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier 'undefined'"

Here's my code:

storage.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AsyncStorage,
} from 'react-native';

module.exports = {
  save: function(key, data){
    //console.log(save key:${key} data:${data} stringify:${JSON.stringify(data)});
    try {
      AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data));
      //console.log(Storage.save() key => value, ${key} => ${JSON.stringify(data)});
      return true;
    } catch(err) {
      //console.log(save: ERROR ${err});
      return false;
    }
  },
  read: async function(key) {
    //console.log(reading key:${key});
    try {
      var data = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      if (data !== null){
        //console.log("Storage.read(): " + typeof(JSON.parse(data)) + ":" + JSON.parse(data));
        return JSON.parse(data);
      }else {
        //console.log("Storage.read(): Not found");
        return false;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      //console.log('Storage.read(): error: ' + err.message);
      return false;
    }
  },
  empty: function(key){
    try {
      AsyncStorage.setItem(key, '');
      //console.log(Storage.empty: cleaning key ${key});
      return true;
    } catch(err) {
      //console.log(Storage.empty: ERROR ${err});
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

index.android.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Alert,
  Image,
  AsyncStorage,
  TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Button, Text } from 'native-base';

import BackgroundImage from './background.js'

var storage = require('./storage.js');

var form_style = require('./formstylesheet.js');

var t = require('tcomb-form-native');
var Form = t.form.Form;

var Person = t.struct({
  Nombre: t.String,
  Apellido: t.String,
  Celular: t.String,
  Lote: t.String,
});

var options = {
  stylesheet: form_style
};


class UserInfo extends Component {
  onPress() {
    var value = this.refs.form.getValue();
    storage.save('username', JSON.stringify(value.Nombre));
    var data = storage.read('username');
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <Image source={require('./images/background.jpg')} style={styles.image_container}>
      <View style={styles.input_container}>
        <Form
          ref="form"
          type={Person}
          options={options}
        />
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.save_button} onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)} underlayColor='#99d9f4'>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Guardar</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
      </Image>
    )
  }
}
```

Not sure if everything needed to solve the problem is in here. Please let me know if I'm missing something, or there's more snippets needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All of `AsyncStorage`'s methods return a `Promise`. In your second snippet, in the `onPress` you are calling `.save()` which calls `AsyncStorage.setItem`. Immediately after, you're calling `.read()` which calls `AsyncStorage.getItem`. You're not waiting for the resolution of the `setItem` Promise hence you're receiving undefined.

Comment: Uh! Newbie problem! Thanks for that. Will give it a try.